# Parse Main Thread Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

So I have an app that's using Parse. I'm able to create new ParseObjects with no problem, as well as query for saved ParseObjects. However, whenever I try to update an existing ParseObject I've queried for, I get the following error:

*"get_bundleIdentifier can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function."*

Now I've found some people getting similar errors, with "get_bundleIdentifier" being the difference, and I think it has to do with not being run from the "main thread", but I don't know how to affect that. I've tried the same code in a coroutine as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441501/main-thread-issue-with-parse-com-queries) and I get the same error.

I'm using Parse Version 1.6.0 and Unity Pro 5.1.2. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class SimpleParseScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("ChallengeScores") // query to parse to find scores and whos turn
            .WhereEqualTo("challengeID", 20307271925313064);
        query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                        {
            ParseObject gameStatus = t.Result;
            print (gameStatus.ObjectId); // print queried ParseObject ObjectId - works fine
            gameStatus["turnsTaken"] = 100;
            Task saveTask = gameStatus.SaveAsync();
        });
    }
}
```

Now, if I comment out "gameStatus["turnsTaken"] = 100;", then try to save it, it runs through just fine, though nothing gets saved for obvious reasons.

Anyone got a clue? The parse documentation [right here](https://www.parse.com/docs/unity/guide#objects-updating-objects) says it should be as simple as declaring it and saving it again after querying, but no go.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution; I thought you could save values on the fly within a query, but I guess saving information to the variable should happen outside of the query.

What I have working now looks something like this:

```
    using Parse;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class MainMenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

    ParseObject parseObjToUpdate; 
    private bool hasUpdatedParse;
    public string myCurrentChalID;

    void Start()
    {
        hasUpdatedParse = false;
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("ChallengeStatus")
            .WhereEqualTo("challengeID", myCurrentChalID);
            query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
             {
                parseObjToUpdate = t.Result;
                print (parseObjToUpdate.ObjectId); // to debug that something is happening and it's the right object
              });
    }

    void Update ()
    {
       if (parseObjToUpdate != null && !hasUpdatedParse)
        {
            parseObjToUpdate["playerTurn"] = PlayerPrefs.GetString("opponentID");
            parseObjToUpdate.SaveAsync();
            hasUpdatedParse = true;
        }
    }
```

So yeah. Gonna mark this as solved. Thank you everyone watching, it's been great.